# Compression when using ASP.NET Core Response.BodyWriter PipeWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, compression

When using the `Response.BodyWriter` property to output JSON from a ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint, it seems the configured compression method is ignored.

Compression is enabled using the recommended `services.AddResponseCompression` and `app.UseResponseCompression` calls in Startup.cs, and indeed this works for normal endpoints that return object instances that are later serialized by the appropriate middleware.

However, using the `PipeWriter` method to write output seems to ignore these settings completely.

Of course, we can write compressed data to the `Response.BodyWriter` pipe directly, but this appears to involve determining the best compression method to use, setting up a Brotli or Gzip writer, and sending chunks through that - all of this is already done by ASP.NET somewhere, so ideally I'd like to avoid re-implementing all this myself.

Is there a standard way to apply the correct compression to the `BodyWriter` pipe?